# wrapfigure in theorem-like environment

Tags: theorems, wrapfigure

The following code does not create a `wrapfigure` within the `thm` environment. Is that because the latter is a list?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{l}{2cm}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}
\end{wrapfigure}%
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `wrapfigure` and `wraptable` environments don't work inside lists; the `wrapfig` documentation clearly mentions this fact:

> The environment must not be placed in special places like lists.

You can use the [`cutwin`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cutwin) package instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\opencutleft
\begin{thm}
\begin{cutout}{2}{0pt}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm\relax}{6}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{cutout}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I knew the [`picins`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex209/contrib/picins/) environment but not the `cutwin` one. Could these three tools be merged in a single one?

Comment: @pluton You're welcome. What do you mean with merging the three tools in one?

Comment: my comment was probably useless. They (wrapfig, picins and cutwin) somehow all have their strengths and weaknesses. That'd be nice to have a single robust package that would decide what to do by itself but it is probably too difficult to implement.

Comment: @pluton Ah, I see. Yes, I agree that a single package would be nice, but, besides technical difficulties, it also  depends on someone taking the time and effort to take the best of the three approaches and writing the package.

Comment: Any other package besides cutwin, shapepar or wrapfig? I need something able to easily wrap text around non-rectangular shapes, without needing to define manually the coordinates for each line.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify does wrapfig work in theorem/lemma/proof environment?