# When wrapping text around an image, latex fills the bottom line first, not the top. How do I fix this?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, wrapfigure

I am using the `wrapfig` package in LaTeX, and in some areas, it is working fine to wrap the text around the image.  However here it is breaking the lines in a weird way, and extending the *blank* area down farther than the image.  I have tried to use `\vspace{-#}` but it is not helping much for this paragraph. Is there a way to fix the blank space or line breaks without manually breaking each line with `\\`?

So for example the line would look like this (sorry it won't let me post a picture...)

1. Search

an item you want to locate in the find tab. (image tight to the word tab)

Corresponding latex:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-.5cm}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{toolbar-find}
\end{center}
\vspace{-5cm}
\end{wrapfigure}

\subsection{Find}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Search an item you want to locate in the find tab. \\
\item Check the box to the left of its name to label it on your screen.\\
\item Double click the object's name to center it on your screen.\\
\item Some objects have two boxes to the right of their name (such as planets). The first box to the right will display the object's orbit, if checked. The second box will display the object's shadow cone, if checked.
\item Further columns to the right give you additional information about the object.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Options}
The options menu allows you to turn on various settings or display items in {\em Starry Night}.  Click the arrow to the left of a section to expand it.  To turn an item on, check the box to its left.  To turn it off, uncheck the box.\\
```

Comment: You can't use `wrapfig` in combination with a list environment: both fight for setting `\parshape` and both lose.

Comment: Oh....It seems to work better in some areas where there is a list environment than where there are others...Is there a package that allows you to wrap text and use a list environment?

Comment: an answer to the question [wrapfigure in theorem-like environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74702/579) suggests using the `cutwin` package.  (i have no personal experience with that package.)

Comment: @egreg Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `wrapfig` in combination with a list environment: both fight for setting `\parshape` and both lose.